# How will i pass the value to the following format?

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to pass the value to a function to get the following url:

search?channelIds=1,2,3&streamName=wew&page=0&size=10

code inside function:

```
$this->request->set("url","broadcasts/pubic/search");
    $this->request->set_fields(array(
    'channelIds'=>$channel_ids,
    'streamName'=>$stream_name,
    'page'=>$page,
    'size'=>$size
    ));
    $result = $this->request->send();
```

Here i pass the values in this format.How will give pass value for channelIds=1,2,3? i use http_build_query for url formation. $channel_ids=array("channelIds"=>1, "channelIds"=>2, "channelIds"=>3); $stream_name="wew"; $page=0; $size=10; $getlivebroadcast = $api-searchBroadcast($channel_ids,$stream_name,$page,$size);

How will i set the value?

Comment: Please put that information into the question.

Comment: You can try using GET, and then making variables out of the GET array

Answer (score 0):

You can use the urlencode function to encode the channel ids. Your function may look like:

```
$this->request->set("url","broadcasts/pubic/search");
    $this->request->set_fields(array(
    'channelIds'=>urlencode($channel_ids),
    'streamName'=>$stream_name,
    'page'=>$page,
    'size'=>$size
    ));
$result = $this->request->send();
```